# AngularJS Controller not defined

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs

So I've been browsing other threads, however none of the fixes I've found have solved my issue. I hope some of the more experienced coders here will be kind enough to help  me out, mods I'm sorry if it turns out I'm being stupid here.

So I've built an app in Angular for an asp.net web app, the angular module should be displaying data from an entity model and displaying it inside a div.

Right now the code is not working, and I have no errors. From what I've seen I suspect its the Booking-controller however I cannot fathom what's wrong.

Here's my code

_Layout.cshtml

```
` <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Web App</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angular")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")


</head>
<body ng-app="BookingsApp">

//a bunch of navbar stuff and other content



    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

`
HomeController.cs

```
`using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace WebApp.Controllers
 {

    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

  //More navigation stuff

  public JsonResult GetAll()
    {
        List<Booking_form> Booking = new List<Booking_form>();
        using (BookingEntities1 ed = new BookingEntities1())
        {
            Booking = ed.Booking_forms.ToList();
            return new JsonResult { Data = Booking, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };

            }

         }



    }
}
```

Page where I expect booking to be displayed

```
    @section scripts{
    <script src="~/Content/Angular/BookingModule.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/Angular/BookingController.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/Angular/BookingService.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/TableStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    }


    <div ng-controller="BookingController">


        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Class</th>
                <th>Day</th>
            </tr>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="e in BookingList">
                <td>{{e.BookingId}}</td>
                <td>{{e.ClassName}}</td>
                <td>
                    {{e.Day}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
```

Angular Module
        `var app = angular.module('BookingsApp',[]);`

Angular Service

```
    app.service('BookingService', function ($http) {
    this.getBookings=function () {
    return $http.get('/HomeController/GetAll');
      }
    });
```

Angular Controller

```
    `app.controller('BookingController',function($scope,BookingService) {
     function getBookingList() {
     BookingService.getBookings().then(function (emp) {

            $scope.BookingList = emp.data;
            }, function (error) {
                alert('Failed to fetch data');
             });
        }
    });
```

`
I'd prefer to have a div on the page displaying the info with the ng-app="BookingApp" line, however this caused the BookingController reference to cause errors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

Having looked again through browser console this message appears for all 3 angular scripts:

```
`Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type application/javascript: "http://localhost:49532/Content/Angular/BookingModule.js".
```

Solved, had to do a complete rebuild and make use of the service factory. For anyone else encountering this issue, see the provided link for a tutorial.

- http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/dhananjay_kumar/archive/2015/05/13/how-to-use-angularjs-in-asp-net-mvc-and-entity-framework-4.aspx

note this solution will not work if solution uses multiple tables with foreign key dependencies.

Comment: Need to do some basic debugging in browser dev tools console and network, there are far too many unknowns for us not to have to make a list of 20 questions

Comment: Yeah break it down into smaller chunks.  Best start is to try and replicate in a Plunker.

Comment: What kind of router do you use? I don't see any `ng-view` or `ui-view` directive in your code.

Comment: @charlietfl I've built it and been through my debugger on chrome, and I've no errors. with no errors I'm currently going through everything line by line and trying to work out where I've gone wrong. I was hoping there would be something glaringly obvious which I had missed because I'm not familiar with angular.

Comment: @Kamo Where would this be required? I built the project as an MVC5 Web app using razor, so most of my routes are defined through an unmodified routeconfig.cs file, however I suppose angular is using a different set of controllers.

Comment: So what does work? Are all the scripts loading in network? Are template requests succeeding? Are data requests succeeding? All can be inspected

Comment: @charlietfl all network requests succeed, angular.js
angular-route.js
modernizr-2.8.3.js
respond.js
browserLink
jquery-2.2.1.js
bootstrap.js
BookingModule.js
BookingController.js
BookingService.js are loaded, apologies submitted too early, bear with

Comment: Ok so it seems the GET request it getting 304 Not Modified, and for the template request there's one there for the data request, although I'm not sure what to do with this new info.

Comment: It would also appear that the module, service and controller are being loaded in css, as well as js, not sure if that's normal

Comment: Does your `$http.get` succeed? - you should be able to view the `response` in browser dev tools -> network -> xhr. Alternatively, `console.log` on specific sections - e.g. check to see `emp` (data). Also, take note on _caSinG_ - e.g. `BookingId` vs `bookingId` (if for example you have set [camelCase on JSON resolver](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm). Hth..

Comment: @EdSF Strangely there doesn't seem to be anything in the xhr tab for the get request. It would appear I misinterpreted the login request as the get last night, my apologies. Can you clarify what console.log checks you would like me to try? As far as I can see the casing is correct.

Comment: Unsure about that styles MIME error, but you can try excluding your stylesheet/s just to focus on JS. You have `function getBookingList()` in your controller that (unless I'm missing it) isn't invoked (probably why you don't see a `GET` in xhr). [`Console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console) is just one handy way you can debug sections - e.g. instead of "alert" - you'll see the output in browser dev tools Console. Hth.

Comment: @EdSF There's a GETALL in the HomeController, which is called by the angular Service, unless I'm mistaken?

Comment: Arg, meant your Angular controller :) - you have a function `getBookingList()` that I don't see run/invoked (just defined).